# How to show firebase auth error messages different in UI

Tags: firebase-authentication

I am using the firebase auth now I want to show a different message in UI for every error message

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for specific error messages in your catch block and add custom handling.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the language you're working in (and I'm not familiar with all of the different libraries), but C# will throw a `FirebaseAuthException` containing the property `AuthErrorCode` which is an enum representing the error.  You could check that in, say, a `switch` statement to get the required message.

```cs
try {
   userRecord = await _FirebaseAuth.GetUserByEmailAsync(email, token)
                                   .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (FirebaseAuthException ex) {
   if (ex.AuthErrorCode == AuthErrorCode.UserNotFound) {
      DisplayError($"Error retrieving user record for {email}");
   }
}
```