# Handle Firebase Auth UI errors in Flutter SignInScreen

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using the firebase_ui_auth: ^1.12.1 package to show SignInScreen but I can't find a way to display a custom message when an error occurs. If, for example, the user enters wrong credentials, I get an exception and a long, not very user-friendly message shows.

```dart
SignInScreen(
    providers: providers,
    actions: [
        AuthStateChangeAction<SignedIn>((context, state) {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/profile');
        }),
    ],
);
```

How can I show a different message or modify how the error message show?

[image: SignInScreen error message]

Comment: You could probably just catch the FirebaseAuthException get the exception code and show a different error message. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72055776/how-to-show-firebase-auth-error-messages-different-in-ui

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);

       
      }  catch (error) {
        var e = error as FirebaseAuthException;
        Print(e.message!);
      }
```

Try this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a class you can use for that. It's also explained in the official document also.

```
 ErrorText
 A widget that displays error text for a given Firebase error code.
```

Check this out example:

```
ErrorText.localizeError = (BuildContext context, FirebaseAuthException e) {
  final defaultLabels = FirebaseUILocalizations.labelsOf(context);

  return switch (e.code) {
    'user-not-found' => 'Please create an account first.',
    'credential-already-in-use' => 'This email is already in use.',
    _ => localizedErrorText(e.code, defaultLabels) ?? 'Oh no! Something went wrong.',
  }
}
```

Or the network errors:

```
ErrorText.localizePlatformError = (BuildContext context, PlatformException e) {
  if (e.code == "network_error") return "Please check your internet connection.";
  return "Oh no! Something went wrong.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [firebase_ui_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_auth) version 1.12.1, the `EmailForm` within the `SignInScreen` is unable to disable the on-screen error messages, catch it and display in our own dialog. Below is the screenshot of the code.

[image: Code screenshot of EmailForm showing the ErrorText]

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Flutter/discussions/285) to request for more custom handling on the error message when authentication failed.